# Incorrect syntax near 'INDEX'

Tags: sql-server

created Index

```
  CREATE INDEX MasterIndex
 ON [Attendance].[dbo].[Attendence] (location,createdby,program,batch,term)
```

tried query

```
SELECT *
 FROM [Attendance].[dbo].[Attendence] USE INDEX (MasterIndex) WHERE createdby='pravin' and term='Term III' and batch='80' and program='computer' and location='AMD'
```

error

> Incorrect syntax near 'INDEX'. If this is intended as a part of a
>   table hint, 
>       A WITH keyword and parenthesis are now required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the WITH Clause

```
SELECT *
 FROM [Attendance].[dbo].[Attendence] WITH (INDEX (MasterIndex)) WHERE ...
```

Comment: @Pravin Happy it helped.

Comment: actually I use indexes for speed up query when compare with index and without index not showing difference in speed why this?

Comment: @Pravin The optimizer will choose an appropriate index,  Good chance you were already using it.

Comment: @Pravin There is a phenomenon of "Index Confusion" where you have an overly index table and even the optimizer will simply hash the table.  This is where WITH INDEX is helpful